# Issue with authentification of spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have choose to do the authentification of my application with Spring Security, i've tested with Google Chrome and it works very well, but when i've tried to test it on Internet Explorer 9, it doesn't work well. the problem is that when i logout and i press the previous button after that it gives me access to the application.

Plz i need some help. Thanks

Comment: How do you handle logout? Manual or j_spring_security_logout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope its not showing a cached page on IE9. Did you try refresh after clicking previous button. If that's the case then i suggest implementing no-caching code in place.

Answer (score 0):

Thank u for your answers, i had to add this part to my spring.xml:

`<interceptors>
        <beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
                <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
                <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="false"/>
                <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
                <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </beans:bean>

     </interceptors>`